# play flash in Android

Tags: android, flash

I'm searching on a subject *"How I can play swf/flash in android"*,but i see we need adobe flash player or something like that and can move on.

after i ask myself *"How works Browsers without any external flash player?"*,I don't understand.

Any one can Help me i see something like [Openfl](http://www.openfl.org/archive/community/programming-haxe/running-swfs-on-android-tablets/),[Lighting Browser](https://github.com/anthonycr/Lightning-Browser).

i can't understand how Openfl work.

any idea?!

Comment: Are you trying to visit a website with Flash content or deploy Flash content to Android as an App?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about OpenFL since I dont I know it well but my understanding is that it just compiles code as SWF without needing some other/expensive Flash compiler.
 
It's **not** an alternative to the Adobe Flash Player (SWF viewer).

As for Lightning browser... if you scroll down the Features list says "Flash support (prior to 4.4)" so it shouldn't show Flash content in latest Android.

Previous versions of Android allowed for installation of **[Flash Player for Android](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)** (scroll down to find)

You could try Firefox on Android :
https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/android/

Firefox is interesting because they have a project : **[Shumway](http://www.areweflashyet.com/shumway/)** which aims to run Flash content (swf files) using HTML5 engine. If you can see this **[race game](http://www.areweflashyet.com/shumway/examples/inspector/inspector.html?rfile=../racing/race3.swf)** on your Android device then you are seeing swf/Flash **without** using Flash Player plugin. Maybe part of that technology is what makes the Firefox app handle Flash content in-browser??